# Mason refers to Amanda as 'Benedict Clarke', is this a cultural reference?

Tags: revenge-tv

In episode 7 of season 2 of [*Revenge*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1837642/), Mason refers to Amanda as 'Benedict Clarke' which I assume is some kind of cultural reference pertaining to her recent activities but I am unable to figure out what it is. Any idea?

Comment: [Benedict Arnold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benedict_Arnold#Infamy_in_the_United_States), maybe? I haven't seen the show, but I've heard of people being referred to as "Benedict [last_name]" in this manner as an insult.

Comment: @MeatTrademark If seen the show or not, that seems sufficient for an answer, given that *Amanda* is indeed a *Clarke* and the plot synopsis seems to include some kind of betrayal from her side.

Comment: @MeatTrademark I would agree seeing as how the most famous benedict clarke is the kid that played young severus snape in Harry Potter Deathly hallow part 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As *MeatTrademark* remarks in his comment (but is reluctant to post as an answer), this might be an allusion to [*Benedict Arnold*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benedict_Arnold), who fought on the American side during the American Revolution but defected to the British. His case and his person have become somewhat of [a model example for treason in modern American culture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benedict_Arnold#Infamy_in_the_United_States), often referenced for this purpose. Though, having only TV and movie experience with modern American culture, I for myself haven't yet *"heard of people being referred to as "Benedict [last_name]" in this manner as an insult"*, but this isn't a far stretch at all and I'd trust *MeatTrademark*'s more practical experience there.

This cultural reference is even more likely when factoring in the additional information from the TV show. *Amanda* is indeed (supposedly) a *Clarke*, and given that [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2465050/?ref_=ttep_ep7) says that in this episode

> Amanda is ready to betray Emily to Mason

this seems like the most probable cultural reference there.